# Why does os.walk(path) not work in the class text_Dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, operating-system, super

I have created a class `text_Dataset` which wants to read the file name. In the `__init__` module,  I do the fetching of the file names in the current directory and store them to the `file_list`.

```
class text_Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path):
        super(text_Dataset, self).__init__()
        self.file_list = [] 
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
            for file in files:
                self.file_list.extend([os.path.join(file)])
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)
```

I created an object dataset, but its length is shown as 0. Apparently `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):` doesn't work

```
dataset = text_Dataset(path)
print(len(dataset)) # 0
```

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please double-check the parameter 'path' you pass in, the codes you post, works well for me. [PS: I removed your Dataset, cause I don't know what the Dataset is]

Comment: Just a guess: `os.walk('')`  is not same as `os.walk('.')` . Otherwise, it works for me too, well, except you might want to put more than a single argument into `os.path.join`.